# Why does a TLS certificate contain the subject name?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

This may be a trivial question but a friend asked me this the other day and I couldn't explain it properly.

So, as far as I know, a TSL certificate contains (among others) the name of the subject and some information used to generate the public key.

The subject would be a domain name like `www.example.com`

Of course, the name of the domain(s) must be included so that only the certificate for example.com and be used on example.com and not the certificate of another domain (certificate swapping).

But (!) it is somehow anchored in my brain that the certificate also identifies the owner (person) in some fashion and proves that the domain is owned by an identified human.

Is this not the case? Is the purpose of a TLS certificate really just mapping public-key-information to a domain name?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no "TLS certificate" only "X.509 ones", as you can do TLS without certificates (with a shared key) and you can use certificates outside of TLS (ex: S/MIME). A certificate is here to prove the identity of something: an hostname, a person name, an organization, an IP address, etc. You can have a certificate about a person, or a certificate about an hostname, but these are two separate certificates. A certificate is here to prove the identity of one thing and one only (ok,to be complete, you can have wildcards for hostnames).Your question is offtopic here though as not about programming.

Comment: A certificate contains the subject name because that's what it's *for:* to authenticate that identity.

Comment: But if I bought a domain and my server points to that domain - why do I need a certificate for that? Obviously, you could make the point that it could be another server operating on a domain that does not belong to it but for most TLS certificates (Wikipedia also uses the term TLS cert - so I'm not sure it's wrong) we only need to prove that we have control over the server pointing to a domain. I really don't see how this "identification", that you guys describe, is achieved?

Comment: I**s the purpose of a TLS certificate really just mapping public-key-information to a domain name?**  TLS Certificate contains the key in addition to identity. Identity determines that the server I am talking to is the authenticated server and key is used to encrypt\decrypt the information between client and the server.